# Git tag, versiones de librería de composer

Tags: git, composer, tags

Tengo una librería de composer que tiene una sere de utilidades que se utilizan en varios proyectos.

El repositorio de esta librería ha sido migrado de un servidor a otro de la siguiente forma.

Clonar repositorio original en un carpeta local:

`git clone --mirror --bare ssh://git@mirepo.com/repos/git/util`

En el nuevo servidor he creado un nuevo repositorio vacío:

`git init --bare util`

Desde el repositorio clonado ejecuté:

`git push --mirror ssh://git@nuevorepo.com/git/util`

Me listó todos los tags que ha subido y hasta ahí todo correcto.

Entonces en el repositorio local hago unos cambios y lo subo de versión a la 2.3.10 por ejemplo, haciendo `git tag 2.3.10` `git push` `git push --tags` pero si me voy al servidor donde está el repositorio nuevo replicado y ejecuto `git tag` me lista solo hasta la 2.3.9

Entonces al intentar instalar la versión 2.3.10 de mi librería no existe dicha versión y no puedo bajarme los cambios.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente falte ajustar tu repositorio local para que use tu nuevo repositorio remoto.

Quieres usar el nuevo repositorio *en vez* del viejo? Entonces podrías abrir el archivo `.git/config`y ajustar el URL del remoto que tienes configurado o usando `git remote --set-url nombre-del-remoto nuevo-url-del-remoto`.

O, si quieres *agregarlo* como un segundo remoto:

```
git remote add el-nombre-del-remoto-nuevo el-url-del-remoto
```

Luego podrías empujar la etiqueta.

Comment: La nueva url ya está puesta en el local.